# Each object has its own memory made up of other objects. Is this still valid in Java?

Tags: java

Put another way, you create a new kind of object by making a package containing existing objects. Thus, you can build complexity into a program while hiding it behind the simplicity of objects.

from [Thinking in Java](http://original.jamesthornton.com/eckel/TIJ-3rd-edition4.0/TIJ3.htm)

Are not all objects independent of each other in Java? Is it possible to create a super object from different objects?

EDIT:

Alan Kay summarized five basic characteristics of Smalltalk way before Java was around. This is one of the characteristics of an OOP according to him. I was wondering if it is still valid for java.

Comment: Think of what a linked list looks like: it *has* a Node element, which is an object.  If I make a list of lists, then the top-level list has a Node, which has a List, which in turn has another Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object can't contain other objects *directly* in Java - but it can certainly hold *references* to other objects. I suspect that's what the author is trying to get across.

So if a `Customer` object knows about the address, phone number, list of orders, name etc, those would all be separate objects... but instead of having to manage all of those explicitly, the *user* of a `Customer` object just keeps a reference to the object, and accesses the rest of the data via that single object.

Comment: +1: Only primitives and references to Objects can be in an Object.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: and when a ref type is an array of primitives, how does the object referred to store it's array of primitive? By using primitives or objects? (the only two choices you're suggesting).  I take it an "array of primitives" is the same as "primitives"?  Or maybe that *"only primitives, references to Objects and array of primitives can be in an Object"* !?   (honest question btw)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r An array is an Object which can contain many primitives, one of which is the length (always an `int`), the rest are accessible by an index.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: cool :)  I never thought about array of primitives that way but it makes perfect sense.  (I knew about the "Object" part of array, but never really thought about the underlying "array" as simply "indexed primitives").  I like it :)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r There is no code for `long[]` but have a look at AtomicLongArray which you might find interesting. ;) http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray-source.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to distinguish two separate concepts:

In memory each object in Java is a separate entity with its own set of memory (and I believe Smalltalk worked the same way). It can reference other objects, which are held in their own memory, but not "contain" other objects within its memory.

Conceptually, there are objects that "belong" to other objects in some way. For example the `char[]` holding the data of a `String` is technically a separate object, but the only other object referencing it is the `String` (and possibly other `String` instances, but let's ignore that at the moment). In this sense, the `String` *contains* the `char[]`.